# Adjust XTerm font colors?

Tags: ubuntu, colors, terminal, xterm

I am using a Virtual Machine in Virtual Box running Lubuntu 14.04. I was wondering how you can adjust the different colors in the terminal window. I usually keep my monitor quite dim so that it is not straining on the eyes, but the downside of this is that darker colors in the terminal window, particularly the shade of blue used, are unreadable. Is there a way to select the R/G/B values of different colors in terminal? I want to bring the blue to be a few shades brighter so that it stands out better on the black background. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It might be a better fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: `man xterm` and search for "background".

Comment: There are several related questions (none of which answer the question, but are equivalent).  I have in mind a better answer than `rtfm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html), there are two ways of setting colors:

- at startup, using X resource settings
- after startup, using escape sequences

For either, the value is normally set as an RGB (red/green/blue) string.  In Debian (and derived distributions such as Ubuntu), there is a package `xtermcontrol` which makes it simple to send escape sequences to set the xterm color palette.  The color(s) for blue are color4 (normal) and color12 (bright).  If you have `xtermcontrol` installed, then you can get the value which is currently used for one of these, e.,g

```
$ xtermcontrol --get-color4
rgb:0000/0000/eeee
```

where "eeee" is the hexadecimal value used for the color4 (normal blue).  The program allows you to *set* a color with a different option, e.g.,

```
$ xtermcontrol --color4=rgb:0000/0000/ffff
$ xtermcontrol --get-color4
rgb:0000/0000/ffff
```

and because the value is printed to the standard output, it would be possible to write a script to retrieve the current color and modify it.

An escape sequence of course, applies only to the xterm in which it is sent.  To apply a similar change to *all* xterm's you would use a resource setting. Typically people use "xrdb -merge" to apply resource settings.  I do not -- rather, I set the XAPPLRESDIR environment variable to point to my own customizable resource files.  Others edit `$HOME/.Xdefaults` (there are several ways to accomplish this).  However color4 is the most likely resource setting to focus on changing.